# Equivalence relations on strongly regular graphs with same parameters

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-isomorphism, algebra

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all [strongly regular graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) with parameter
$(n, k, \lambda, \mu)$. Are there any (interesting) equivalence relations defined on this set?

My motivation is to approach isomorphism partition (equivalence relation is *being isomorphic*) via other coarser partition.

Comment: You can imagine any number of equivalence relations on graphs: via chromatic number, clique number, isomorphism, etc.  They seem to remain as interesting on this particular restricted set.

Comment: I am interested in equivalence relation which can be computed in polynomial time AND induce a partition coarser than isomorphism partition.